# PowerShell remove last sub folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is there a way how to remove only last empty folder with PowerShell? 

Example: I have a folder structure

***..-mainFolder 

...................-subFolder1 

........................................- a

........................................- b

........................................- c

..................-subFolder2

........................................- a

........................................- b***

Every night with robocopy i copy everything to another server and afterword i should delete all last sub folders (**a,b,c, etc..**).

With /MUVE it removes "**subFolder1**" & "**subFolder2**" but they should stay there

(if i remove folders "a", "b", "c" the "subFolder1" is empty too so i cant delete all empty folders.)

I cant use /FX and i don't know the name of folders just root directory path 
*"C:\SharedFolders\"*. and i know that the folders that should be removed is in 3rd level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet with the `-Directory` switch to retrieve all folders, filter the empty folders using the [Test-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113418) cmdlet and finally delete the folders using [Remove-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\SharedFolders' -Directory -Recurse | 
  where { -not (Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName '*')) } | 
  Remove-Item
```

This will remove only the last empty folders, result:

```
..-mainFolder 
...................-subFolder1 
..................-subFolder2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to retrieve all folders, then call the `GetFiles()` and `GetDirectories()` methods on the directory objects to determine if they are empty:

```
$EmptyDirs = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\mailFolder -Directory -Recurse | Where {-not $_.GetFiles() -and -not $_.GetDirectories()}
# and then remove those
$EmptyDirs | Remove-Item
```